Do algebras that form a part of Schur-Weyl duality always approach orthogonality?
Consider the representation $P_d$ of the symmetric group $S_n$ on the space $(\mathbb{C}^d)^n$ defined
as
$$
P_d(\sigma)= \sum_{i_1,\dots i_n} |i_1\dots i_n\rangle\langle i_{\sigma(1)}\dots i_{\sigma(n)}|.
$$
One can then define the Hilbert Schmidt norm on this space as
$$
\langle A,B\rangle = \mathrm{Tr}(A^{\dagger}B)/\mathrm{Tr}(I_{d^n})
$$
and the corresponding Gram matrix $G_{\sigma,\tau}:= \langle P(\sigma)|P(\tau)\rangle$. In the large Hilbert space dimension, the Gram matrix approaches the identity $I_{n!}$. Simply stated, this corresponds to the orthogonality of permutations as $d\rightarrow \infty$. One can see this by explicitly evaluating the Gram matrix for the case of permutations as $G_{\sigma,\tau} = d^{C(\sigma^{-1}\tau)-n}$, where $C(.)$ is the cycle function on permutations, and taking the $d\rightarrow\infty$ limit.
The above actually happens to be true when we lose the group structure such as in the case of the Brauer algebra. However, every work I find on this subject explicitly evaluates the Gram matrix to conclude the approach of the Gram matrix to the identity in both these cases. One thing to note is that both the permutation and Brauer algebras are centralizers of the n-fold tensor product action of the Unitary groups $U(d)$ and $O(d)$ respectively (Schur-Weyl duality). My guess is that this is a consequence of some sort of measure concentration result due to averaging over Unitary and Orthogonal group moments. However, I am not sure. Does anybody know of a more general way to conclude the orthogonality of representations of these algebras in the large Hilbert space dimension without explicit evaluation?
